# How to prove something by using a definition?

Tags: coq, coqide

If I define multiplication like this (`drugi_c`), how do I prove e.g. `X*0=0`?
(How to prove something by the definition?)

```
Fixpoint drugi_c(x y: nat): nat:=

 match x, y with
  | _, O => O
  | O, _ => O
  | S O, _ => y
  | _,S O => x
  | S x', S y' => plus y (drugi_c x' y)
end.

Notation "x * y" := (drugi_c x y) (at level 40, left associativity).
```

Whenever I use "simpl." in proofs instead of 0 = 0, i get the definition in result.

```
Lemma neka2 x:
   x * 0 =  0.
Proof.
   induction x.
  -simpl. reflexivity.
  -simpl. (*right here*)
Abort.
```

Result after the last simpl.

```
1 subgoal
x : nat
IHx : x * 0 = 0
______________________________________(1/1)
match x with
| 0 | _ => 0
end = 0
```

What to write after that last `simpl.` to finish the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Your goal has a pattern match on `x`, but no matter what value `x` is it will return 0. To force this to simplify, you can `destruct x`.

Note that you never use the inductive hypothesis here, so you could have done `destruct x` at the beginning instead of `induction x`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i end up getting:

```
Lemma neka2 x:
   x * 0 =  0.
Proof.
 destruct x.
  -simpl. reflexivity.
  -simpl. (**) 
Abort.
```

Result:

```
1 subgoal
x : nat
______________________________________(1/1)
x * 0 = 0
```

I guess you have to prove it with induction because same thing happens when I try to destruct x with predefined mult as well.

Here is x*0=0 proof but with predefined mult:

```
Theorem mult_0_r : forall n:nat,
  n * 0 = 0.
Proof.
  intros n.
  induction n as [|n'].
  Case "n = 0".
    simpl.
    reflexivity.
  Case "n = S n'".
    simpl.
    rewrite -> IHn'.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

As @user138737 pointed out, you don't need induction. It is sufficient to explore three cases : `x = 0`, `x = 1` and `x = S (S x'))`. The shortest proof I can come with is thus the following.

```
destruct x as [| [|] ]; reflexivity.
```